# Determine two lists are equal without caring about ordering Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, matcher

I have got into a situation where I am stubbing through when-then to match a list but I am getting error most of the times due to ordering issue.

```
List<String> myListToMatch = new ArrayList<String>();
myListToMatch .add("1");
myListToMatch .add("2");
when(obj.methodName(eq(myListToMatch))).thenReturn("someStringValue");
```

Due to ordering as in the called method the list go as ["2","1"] which is not returning "someStringValue" as per the above stubbing which is affecting my test case.  Any help is appreciated. I am using Mockito library. I dont have any hamcrest dependency(dont want to add any).

I tried sorting in the code and it works but I dont want to update my code if there is way or some kind of argument matcher which I can use in when-then stubbing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you do not care about the ordering of elements, you could go for a Set instead. Alternatively you could also follow the implementation given in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700998/7803797) that closely aligns with your problem statement.

If you are using Java 8, and newer versions of Mockito you could write the following piece of code. Its taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50551476/7803797)

```
when(
   mock.method(argThat(t -> t.containsAll(Arrays.asList("1","2"))))
).thenReturn(myValue);
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Hi @Chaitanya Waikar, The link you shared helps but not fitting my case. I cannot use separate dependency like hamcrest and I cannot make any update to the code. I need to work with the test case to do eq(myListToMatch) without taking care of ordering.

Comment: @SiddharthShankar which version of mockito and java are you using?

Comment: You could at least link to the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883990/matching-list-in-any-order-when-mocking-method-behavior-with-mockito) where you found this solution ;)

Comment: @Chaitanya Waikar  Using Java8 and Mockito 1.7

Comment: @michalk added. Thanks. Forgot to add it in a hurry

Comment: @Chaitanya Waikar I am not much familiar with few Java8 concepts. I updated the test with your suggestion. Its prompting me this:  "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface". Tried looking at solution for it but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: `t.containsAll` does not actually check equality. If just checks that t contains the requested elements, e.g. as a subset.

Comment: @SiddharthShankar ... If you are not familiar with lambda expressions, it might be easier for you to write a custom argument matcher with the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually care about the number of occurrences, the easiest way is to construct a `Map<String, Long>`, where the key is an element in the list, and the value is the number of occurrences of that element:

```
Map<String, Long> map =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()));
```

Construct this map for each of the expected and actual lists, then compare them for equality.